# Git: Fast way to checkout all tagged versions of a file

Tags: git

Is there a fast way to checkout all tagged versions of a file from a local git repo?

I am currently using the command "git checkout MyTag MyFile.txt" in a loop for each tag.
The problem here is that this command takes 50ms to execute, which quickly accumulates to many seconds when there are 50-100 tags. The information is needed for a user interface, so several seconds of delay is unacceptable.

I have tried "git show MyTag:MyFile.txt", but it also takes 50ms.
It seems git has a standard execution time of 50ms. Even "git --version" takes about 50ms to execute.

I am using git version 1.9.5 for windows.

Comment: If `git --version` takes 50 ms, I would not expect any more speed from `git checkout` (although you could always try this on a different OS and/or different hardware).  (Aside: git tags specific commits, not specific files, but that has no effect on your question.)

Comment: If there is a way to reduce git execution time for each "git checkout", then that would be one solution.
But another solution would be if there is a single git command which is capable of retrieving all versions of a single file. Something similar to "git log -p MyFile.txt", but it would have to return the full file for each version.
(I am aware that tags are on commits. I only need a single file from each of those commits)

Comment: You *can* get `git show` to show multiple files: `git show A:file.txt B:file.txt`.  The problem is that there's no obvious separation between them.  One more possibility, that requires a fair bit of programming: `git cat-file --batch=<format>` (see the man page).  Feed it the file identifiers (`<tag>:<path>` will suffice) on stdin and read according to your `<format>` on stdout, choosing something that will let you separate the files (specifically, the `%(objectsize)` in bytes).

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. It will take some programming as you say, but I will have a go at it and see how it works out.

Comment: It worked out quite well.
Just a warning to anyone else trying this: "git cat-file" expects LF separating each line on stdin, while git for windows will obviously by default get CRLF from stdin. The easiest solution is to put the file-list in a file and pipe that file to stdin.